# Programmatically "clicking" a Pushbutton

Tags: c#, pdf, datagridview, itext

I've got a PDF-Form-template which I want to create Spell-Cards for a tabletop game using objects I get from a Datagridview (the "spell"-object in the Example-Code). I already set most of the values, because most of them are just plain text.

However some of them are buttons which behave like a Radiobutton, but I noticed that these are just two Pushbuttons on top of each other (for example the "verbal on" and "verbal icon" buttons).

Is there any way to programmatically perform a click on a Pushbutton using ItextSharp?

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,new FileStream(outputFolder+Path.DirectorySeparatorChar+spell.Name+".pdf",FileMode.Create));
AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;
fields.SetField("spell level", spell.Level.ToString());
fields.SetField("Spell Name", spell.Name);
fields.SetField("Spell Type", spell.Type);
PushbuttonField button = fields.GetNewPushbuttonFromField("verbal on");
PushbuttonField button2 = fields.GetNewPushbuttonFromField("verbal icon");
//Something like button.PerformClick()?
stamper.Close();
```

Comment: do the pushButton's execute any code ?

Comment: You could put whatever code that's currently executed in the click event into a common method, and then call that method from both the click event and from wherever you want to simulate a button click.

Comment: IText does not contain a JavaScript interpreter. Therefore, it cannot out of the box run the JavaScript code in question